# Dynamic programming algorithm involving combinations?

Tags: java, dynamic

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxSxL.jpg)

So that problem is solved by this algorithm

```
public int rob(int[] nums) {
    if (nums.length == 0) return 0;
    int[] memo = new int[nums.length + 1];
    memo[0] = 0;
    memo[1] = nums[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
        int val = nums[i];
        memo[i+1] = Math.max(memo[i], memo[i-1] + val);
    }
    return memo[nums.length];
}
```

I am not able to follow this dynamic programming approach, I cannot get out of the idea of iterative programming. I keep wanting to create currentMax variables etc, but it serves no purpose.

Is it possible to explain what is going on here, and the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to explain the nature of this problem and I hope it will follow - Think in terms that if there are only two houses `< h1 <cost: 90>, h2 <cost: 100>>`. What would be the answer? One would go for `h2`. This is our base case of the problem and we will extend it from here.extension - 3 houses - `<h1 <cost: 90>, h2 <cost: 100>, h3 < cost: 75>>`. If you loot `h2` , you can not loot `<h1> and <h3>` but you want to loot `<h1> and <h3>`because it gives you more sum. so, recursively, at a current time t,if I store my result in a variable `dp` and a `recursive func(int index,int[] array)`, I can frame answer as `dp[index]=max(arr[index]+dp[index+2],dp[index+1])`. It states that if I loot `ith House`, then I can not loot `next house`, so remaining problem to solve is from `i+2th index`

Answer (score 0):

In this pattern it is storing the max among a previous result and current value of num in current position of memo and so on